# Facing a builtins.ValueError and a problem with deleting a specific row from a csv file

Tags: python, compiler-errors, delete-row

I'm facing an error which i know its commonly seen but there is always some small issue which i can't figure out.
I also did a delete function but it deletes everything in the csv file instead of a specific row even with the error. What is the right way to do this function?

After editing the code it still gives the same error so I hope i can get some help here thanks!

The data format in my csv:

```
name    tribe      id    Air  Water Earth Fire
Aang    Normad    N321B   89   67     54   78
Gyatso  Omaticaya O111C   54   78     65   54
```

```
def insert_avatar():

    filePath = "data.csv"
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        filePath = "sample_write_data.csv"
    with open(filePath,'a',newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['name','tribe','id','Air','Water','Earth','Fire']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)

        print("Insert a new avatar")

        name = input("Enter Name:")

        three_integer = int(input("Enter id three integers:"))

        tribename = input("Enter tribe:")

        air = int(input("Air:"))

        water = int(input("Water:"))

        earth = int(input("Earth:"))

        fire = int(input("Fire:"))

        id_F_letter = tribename[0].upper()
        average_power = (air + water + earth + fire)/4

        if average_power >=80:
            last_letter = 'A'

        elif average_power >= 70:
            last_letter ='B'

        elif average_power >= 60:
            last_letter ='C'

        elif average_power >=50:
            last_letter ='D'

        elif average_power >= 40:
            last_letter ='E'

        else:
            last_letter = 'F'


        ID = id_F_letter + str(three_integer)+ last_letter    

        print("New Avatar with ID {0} Inserted".format(ID))

        info =[]    
        Avatar_List ={}
        Avatar_List['name'] = name
        Avatar_List['id'] = ID
        Avatar_List['tribe'] = tribename
        Avatar_List['Air'] = air
        Avatar_List['Water'] = water
        Avatar_List['Earth'] = earth
        Avatar_List['Fire'] = fire        

        info.append(Avatar_List)

        for dictionary in info:
            if csvfile.tell() == 0:
                writer.writeheader()

            writer.writerow(dictionary)
```

```
def d_avatar():
    filePath = "data.csv"
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        filePath = "sample_write_data.csv"
    with open(filePath,'w',newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['name','tribe','id','Air','Water','Earth','Fire']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)

        print("Delete an avatar")
        deletion = input("Enter avatar id to delete: ")

        for row in reader:
            if row['id'] == deletion:
                del row


                print("Avatar Record Deleted")
```

Comment: can u show how your `data.csv` looks like ?

Comment: i can't show an image here so sorry:( i can say these are my column names  ['name','tribe','id','Air','Water','Earth','Fire'] , the last 4 columns are integers and the first 3 is strings if it helps . It is in an excel file format.

Comment: Not the image, I mean just post the content of the csv in the question

Comment: previously i did an insert function already it is able to insert but i can't figure out how to do a delete and i have a builtins.ValueError too with this delete function only.

Comment: Please include the csv content and and example on input avatar in the question

Comment: Please include the csv content and and example on input avatar in the question

Comment: okay done it! I have inserted my insert avatar function too if it helps.